# how to get the value of two sliders during sliding?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

I have two sliders in my view and I want to get both value when I slide each one .
but whenever I try to do this the value of the other slider which is not sliding becomes zero and literally I get only one value.

this is what I have done

- create two IBAction for each slider
- create two property for each slider

  @property (retain , nonatomic ) IBOutlet UISlider * slider2;

  ```
  -(IBAction) slidingN : (id) sender
  {

      UISlider * si = (UISlider *) sender;
      int value = (int) si.value;
      NSString * newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i" , value];

      myLable.text = newText;

      int valueD = (int)slider2.value;
      [self callSubView:value :valueD];
  }
  ```

but the value is 0 how can I have both values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved (surpassingly) after restarting Xcode